# How to style answers from the Answers module to make them look as in the demo site?

Tags: theming, 7

The voting element of the [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers) module does not look as in the following screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

What should I do to make them appear as in the screenshot?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about _Implementing a functionality or a layout seen in a site, for which just a description of the feature, a screenshot, or a site URL is provided_

Answer (score 1):

First you should enable vote_up_down Field module too, so you can add it to your preferred content-type (e.g answers), while adding it, in settings it asks which kind of widget to use; set it as default, then it will be like in your picture, without any need of altering the used CSS styles. If you still dont get your desired look, it must be the CSS styles that are overwritten. Inspect the element, and look for it.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Vote Up / Down does not seem to work for me in D7 due to thsi  issue - http://drupal.org/node/1194274. I guess I will have to style the rating widget that comes with answers by default.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot in the question here is from the prior release of the [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers) module, and the demo site where that screenshot originated from does not exist anymore (now replaced by a [new demo site](http://drupal.placeto.be/module/answers)).

The newest 7.x-4.0 version comes with the (new) `Answers Theme` sub-module, which, out-of-the-box, transforms the (rather boring) vanilla display of a Question (and its related Answers below it), into a way more attractive look-and-feel. Such as the orange bubble that is added around the question (to better highlight it). If you don't enable this sub-module, then you get a similar vanilla display (still).

To see this newest version at work, head over to this [example question](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/50) (from its new demo site). Here is a screenprint that is pretty close to what's included in the newest version:

[image]

Something that I think make sense as a future enhancement of this (new) sub-module, is to add a notion of "skins", consisting of a combination of CSS and/or JS, so that the purely theming (colors, buttons, etc) could be done as much as possible by tuning the delivered skins, or creating your own new skins.

Disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers).